# Filling up a table about a chemical reaction

Tags: stoichiometry, mole

I am filling up this table but I'm not sure about what it means in the mass row, amount of substance, molecule quantity.

In mass do I just have to repeat 16 in the second column or do I need to put the mass of a single molecule?

Amount of substance 1 mole of the molecule or 5 moles of each atom?

I'm confused.

[image: Table]

Comment: Is this some reaction that you carried out in a lab? Is there any other context to the question? If this is all that you were given, in the absence of any further detail, it is completely unclear what mass you are supposed to be putting in, so it's quite fair that you're confused.

Comment: Well not any other context than there is this simulator for chemical reaction balance, and the chemical reaction in the table comes in there, you have to solve all the other data after balancing the reaction. But the simulator does not contain any other data, just the reaction and blank boxes in the coefficients to balance it, like a game. thats it.

Comment: I think they just want you understand the various meanings of a balanced equation. For CH4, molar mass is 16 g/mol, mass is 16 grams, Amount of substance =1 mol, molecule quantity =1